# using componentDidMount and componentWillRecieveProps methods not able to fetch the props testHighlight from parent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am new to react. I am trying to include `react-highlight-words` into my application for searching the text. So I created a simple search textbox,  where we can search the text. Right now my text box is inside `SearchBar.js` and the highlighter component code is inside `Highlighter.js` there I used `componentDidMount` and `componentWillRecieveProps` to retrive the `testHighlight` values from the parent `SearchBar` component. But its **not printing** the values, so I am not able to pass inside `Highlighter`.

Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.

Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp1p2zvl4

**SearchBar.js**

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      testHighlight: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value); // your search bar text
    let object = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    console.log(object.textContent); // your div text

    // now that you have the two strings you can do your search in your favorite way, for example:

    let searchBarText = e.target.value;
    console.log("searchBarText --->", searchBarText);

    let divText = object.textContent;
    console.log("divText --->", divText);

    if (divText.includes(searchBarText)) {
      console.log("the div text contains your search text");
    } else {
      console.log("the div text doesn't contain search text");
    }

    // this.setState({ testHighlight: response.data });

    this.setState({ testHighlight: searchBarText });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="input"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Search..."
          // highlightText={this.handleChange}
          testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Highlighter.js**

```
class Highlighter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount---->", this.props.testHighlight);
  }

  componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("componentWillRecieveProps---->", this.props.testHighlight);
    if (this.props.testHighlight !== nextProps.testHighlight) {
      this.setState({ testHighlight: nextProps.testHighlight });
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Highlighter
          highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
          //searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
          searchWords={this.props.testHighlight}
          autoEscape={true}
          textToHighlight="The dog is chasing the cat. Or perhaps they're just playing?"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are not implementing Highlighter.js. You need to add it inside of your return method in SearchBar.js and pass the props to it like so:

```
<Highlighter
  testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight}
/>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...if I update your code I am getting error, providing my updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp1p2zvl4 can you directly fix it in my sandbox

Comment: So you have 2 problems:
1: In searchbar you are importing Highlighter from react-highlighter instead of your highlighter, so fix your imports
2: You can't have 2 different components both named Highlighter. 

In this case, you can get rid of your highlighter component and import the react highlighter directly into your SearchBar component. Then just pass the searchWords directly.

Comment: hey I am trying to learn parent child implementation, so I wanted highlight as child component, have updated my code...can you help me so that I will understand much better HighlighterImplementation https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp1p2zvl4

Comment: Your testHighlight in SearchBar should be an array, not an object. You are passing in an object which it is calling "filter" on.... Filter can only be called on an array.

Comment: hey it worked but can you tell me how to figure out when to pass object or array, now if I type anything in the search textbox again I am facing an error, providing updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp1p2zvl4

Comment: You will have to look at the API documentation for that component. React Highlighter should have documentation as to what props each component can accept and what type they should be ("String", "Integer", "Object", "Array", etc).

Comment: Also whenever you are setting the state (whenever you update text) in your SearchBar, you are setting "testHighlight" to be a string. You will want this to be an array and insert the text into the array.

Comment: Also if any of this is helpful can you upvote it? I need more upvotes so I can upvote and comment.

Comment: yeah I looked at the documenation they have mentioned searchWords as an array this is what you where referring? I changed searchBarText to an array but still I am facing problem, providing my updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp1p2zvl4  let searchBarText = [];  once its working I will accept your answer ...I have done for others too

Comment: sorry providing updated sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/00nm6k8orp

Comment: When you are handling the search bar text change you are changing it from an array to a string:
      let searchBarText = [];
      searchBarText = e.target.value;

It needs to still be an array, so you should do something like this: searchBarText.push(e.target.value). Or just put it in index 0.

Comment: hey but this line is chnaging into array right `let searchBarText = [],` do I need to assign the value using push operation then only will it become array I thought if we assign like this also we are assigning it in an array `searchBarText = e.target.value; `